# Python split row in two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
name     height       width
apple    [180, 191]   [10, 20]
orange   [50, 130]    [15, 30]
```

How can I split `height` and `width` into: `height-min`, `height-max`, `width-min`, `width-max` using pandas?

Comment: are these lists or strings? are they always sorted or not?

Comment: They are a list of numbers, and not sorted. Just in min-max values

Comment: if it's already min-max format, then the linked duplicate should work for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following by splitting on the comma and removing your square brackets.

```
df['min-height'] = df['height'].str.split(',').str[0].str.strip('[]')
df['max-height'] = df['height'].str.split(',').str[1].str.strip('[]')
df['min-width'] = df['width'].str.split(',').str[0].str.strip('[]')
df['max-width'] = df['width'].str.split(',').str[1].str.strip('[]')
```

This will create new columns for you